# Display excel file from assets folders in an android application

Tags: android, excel, android-activity, android-assets

Can any one help me to

**display an excel file taking from assets folder in an android application**

I can't make it out to display file.
I used POI jar file also to display that file...Please send me the code

i tried from sd card but i can't make from assets

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity 
{
    String dbStr = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/dropbox/xls/stock1.xls";
    String strHyouji="";
    String[][] arrays = read();
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        if(arrays == null)
        {
            strHyouji="no such file";
        }
        else
        {
            for (String[] array : arrays) 
            {
                for (String v : array) 
                {
                    strHyouji = strHyouji + v + ",";
                }
                strHyouji = strHyouji + "\n";
            }
        }
        TextView textSetting = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        textSetting.setText(strHyouji);
    }
    public String[][] read() 
    {
        Workbook workbook = null;
        try 
        {
            WorkbookSettings ws = new WorkbookSettings();
            ws.setGCDisabled(true);
            workbook = Workbook.getWorkbook(new File(dbStr), ws);
            Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheet(0);

            int rowCount = sheet.getRows();
            String[][] result = new String[rowCount][];
            for (int i = 0; i < rowCount; i++) 
            {
                Cell[] row = sheet.getRow(i);
                result[i] = new String[row.length];
                for (int j = 0; j < row.length; j++) 
                {
                    result[i][j] = row[j].getContents();
                }
            }
            return result;
        }
        catch (BiffException e) 
        {
            strHyouji=strHyouji+ e.toString();

        }
        catch (IOException e) 
        {
            strHyouji=strHyouji+ e.toString();
        }
        catch (Exception e) 
        {
            strHyouji=strHyouji+ e.toString();
        }
        finally 
        {
            if (workbook != null) 
            {
                workbook.close();
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

**Mail : ravitejabrt@gmail.com**

Answer (score 1):

Late response.But it will be used  for someone...

Try this...

*Don't forget to have Excel file in AssetFolder.*

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements OnClickListener {

 private Button btnReadExcel1;
 AssetManager assetManager;

 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

  btnReadExcel1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnReadExcel1);

  btnReadExcel1.setOnClickListener(this);

  assetManager = getAssets();

 }


 @Override
 public void onClick(View v) {

  if (v.getId() == R.id.btnReadExcel1) {

   readExcelFileFromAssets();

  }

 }

 public void readExcelFileFromAssets() {

  try {
   // Creating Input Stream
   /*
    * File file = new File( filename); FileInputStream myInput = new
    * FileInputStream(file);
    */

   InputStream myInput;

                       //  Don't forget to Change to your assets folder excel sheet
   myInput = assetManager.open("contacts.xls");

   // Create a POIFSFileSystem object
   POIFSFileSystem myFileSystem = new POIFSFileSystem(myInput);

   // Create a workbook using the File System
   HSSFWorkbook myWorkBook = new HSSFWorkbook(myFileSystem);

   // Get the first sheet from workbook
   HSSFSheet mySheet = myWorkBook.getSheetAt(0);

   /** We now need something to iterate through the cells. **/
   Iterator<Row> rowIter = mySheet.rowIterator();

   while (rowIter.hasNext()) {
    HSSFRow myRow = (HSSFRow) rowIter.next();
    Iterator<Cell> cellIter = myRow.cellIterator();
    while (cellIter.hasNext()) {
     HSSFCell myCell = (HSSFCell) cellIter.next();
     Log.e("FileUtils", "Cell Value: " + myCell.toString()+ " Index :" +myCell.getColumnIndex());
     // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "cell Value: " +
     // myCell.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
   }
  } catch (Exception e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
  }

  return;
 }
}
```

Comment: Remember to close file, input stream resources when done. I mean you can add a finally clause like:  
finally{
            if (pOIFSFileSystem != null)
            {
                try
                {
                    pOIFSFileSystem.close();
                }
                catch (IOException e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace(out);
                    throw e;
                }
            }
        }

This also can be applied to inputstream